# Выгрузка из ad пользователей, которые хранятся в текстовом файле

Tags: powershell

Есть такой такой скриптик :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like ' Петров Иван Иванович'} -Properties
name,whenCreated, extensionAttribute4 , extensionAttribute5 | Select
name,extensionAttribute4,extensionAttribute5, whenCreated  | Export-CSV
c:\ps\user_AD_02.csv -Append -Encoding UTF8
```

Это по одному пользователю. Как сделать по списку из файла (примерно 2000 фио и из разных доменов, двух доменов) никак не разберусь. Может, есть готовое решение?

Comment: А где пример файла, из которого берутся данные? Никто ж не знает что из себя он представляет, какова его структура, верно?

Comment: да подзабыл подтянуть , файл выглядит так : это сsv на каждой строке по ФИО  и таких строк 2800
 Абдулин Эрик Юратович 
 Абдулова Евгения Юрьевна
 Абенов Вадим Айткалиевич

Comment: Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос таким образом, чтобы в самом вопросе был приведен небольшой фрагмент _csv_, и поясните на счет доменов, откуда они берутся.